# ng-minlength less than a whole number

Tags: angularjs

I'm using the code below in an application:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="waste.Quantity" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="1" ng-pattern="/^([1-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)$/" />
```

As you can see I have validation set on minimum length 1 
Unfortunately for me customers need to enter decimals i.e. 0.5 NOT just whole numbers.

Is it possible to validate so anything equal or over 0.1 is passed?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-minlenght` restricts the number of characters not the actual value, `ng-pattern` is your problem it's validating to accept only integers. something like `/^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/` would accept decimals

Comment: Thanks Fabio.  I've updated my controller however when I enter 0.5 and save the number reverts back to 0

Comment: My controller code:  var hasFinishedQuantity = /^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/g.test(waste.FinishedQuantity.toString().trim());

Comment: Sorted the issue.  My field was set to int NOT decimal.